# nomencl manually sorting

Tags: sorting, nomenclature

I have a problem with manually sorting the entries for my nomenclature by the prefixes, and I cannot get it to work. Here is my code; they are supposed to be sorted by the numbers in the prefixes, i.e. in the order they are written here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

% cd C:\THE FOLDER\makeindex reportneu.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o reportneu.nls

\printnomenclature[2cm]
\nomenclature[1]{$A,B$}{Countries $A,B$.}
\nomenclature[2]{$C$}{Fixed cost}
\nomenclature[3]{$\underline{C}$}{The lower bound}%
\nomenclature[6]{$E$}{The equilibrium tax rates for the symmetric case.}
\nomenclature[8]{$n$}{The size factor}
\nomenclature[9]{$\overline{n}$}{The value}
\nomenclature[10]{$p_A,p_B$}{The price}
\nomenclature[15]{$\Pi_{kl}$}{The total operating profits }
\nomenclature[20]{$\emptyset$}{The non-entry option}

\end{document}
```

where `makeindex reportneu.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o reportneu.nls` is what I enter in the command line (filename is reportneu.tex)

Here is what I tried:
- rename the file, and change the code "makeindex reportneu.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o reportneu.nls" accordingly, to run it freshly - result: the nomenclature stayed in the same order (the default order, apparently; it goes: $A,B$ < $p_A,p_B$ < $\Pi_{kl}$ < ... < $\overline{n}$)

- delete all latex files except for the .tex-file in the directory - no effect
- delete one row in the above nomenclature and run the makeindex-command again: Effect: the nomenclature did not include that entry anymore, but the remaining order stayed the same.
- try both `\usepackage[intoc,noprefix]{nomencl}` and `\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}` - no effect

there is also no error when I execute the `makeindex`-command, look:

```
C:\Arbeit\Unisachen\Fall 2012\Managerial Economics>makeindex reportneu.nlo -
s nomencl.ist -o reportneu.nls
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist...
.......done (10 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file reportneu.nlo....done (20 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (104 comparisons).
Generating output file reportneu.nls....done (46 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in reportneu.nls.
Transcript written in reportneu.ilg.
```

(there are 20 entries in total, I left most out here). Any help is looked forward to and greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sorting order *is* correct, because it is performed lexicographically on the prefixes:

> 1 10 15 2 20 3 6 8 9

Say

```
\nomenclature[01]{$A,B$}{Countries $A,B$.}
\nomenclature[02]{$C$}{Fixed cost}
\nomenclature[03]{$\underline{C}$}{The lower bound}%
\nomenclature[06]{$E$}{The equilibrium tax rates for the symmetric case.}
\nomenclature[08]{$n$}{The size factor}
\nomenclature[09]{$\overline{n}$}{The value}
\nomenclature[10]{$p_A,p_B$}{The price}
\nomenclature[15]{$\Pi_{kl}$}{The total operating profits }
\nomenclature[20]{$\emptyset$}{The non-entry option}
```

(0 comes before the other digits)

Your MWE is not correct: you need to typeset something in order that the `.nlo` file is output. Just add a word after `\begin{document}`. Here's what I get:

[image]